# PyTorch Unit-testing in Python

Tags: python, beginner, unit-testing, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch and I'm writing a unit test for an activation function I'm making.

I plan to test against a reference implementation for this function. I want to approach this in a test-driven way, so I learned to write a test using a known-good function: the ReLU implementation "MyReLU" from  [this beginner tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html).

The tests passed, but is there any way I can improve the code below? I worry I might not be taking full advantage of PyTorch's libraries and capabilities.

```
import unittest
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.autograd import gradcheck
from my_activation_functions import MyReLU

class ReluTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.relu = MyReLU.apply

    def test_relu_values_x_leqz(self):
        tin_leqz = torch.tensor(np.linspace(-10,0,300))
        tout_leqz = list(self.relu(tin_leqz))
        for x in tout_leqz:
            self.assertEqual(x,0)

    def test_relu_values_x0(self):
        tin_eqz = torch.tensor([0,0,0,0,0])
        tout_eqz = list(self.relu(tin_eqz))
        for x in tout_eqz:
            self.assertEqual(x,0)

    def test_relu_values_x_geqz(self):
        tin_geqz = torch.tensor(np.linspace(0.001,10,300))
        tout_geqz = list(self.relu(tin_geqz))
        test_geqz = list(tin_geqz)
        for ii in range(len(tout_geqz)):
            self.assertEqual(tout_geqz[ii], test_geqz[ii])

    def test_drelu_values(self):
        tin = (torch.randn(20,20,dtype=torch.double,requires_grad=True))
        self.assertTrue(gradcheck(self.relu, tin, eps=1e-6, atol=1e-4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are asking about PyTorch's capabilities you are not taking advantage of, you might want to use:

- `torch.linspace(-10,0,300)` instead of `torch.tensor(np.linspace(-10,0,300))`
- `torch.zeros(5, dtype=torch.long)` instead of `torch.tensor([0,0,0,0,0])`
- tensor operations instead of iterating over each element of the tensor in a loop. This might not matter much in unit-tests but is important if you want to get GPU acceleration:

  `self.assertTrue(torch.equal(tout_leqz, torch.zeros_like(tin_leqz)))`